# Angular, pass parameter from view to directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm very new in angular and Javascript so maybe its a stupid question...

I need put information from a controller (route.id) to a view to be interpreted by a directive that will be translated to other directive. I'm sorry but I can't explain better. I've done a code simplification:

index.html

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-ctrl="myctrl">
   <adir aattr="{{param}}" >
   </adir>
</div>
```

myapp.js:

```
angular.module("myapp",[])
    .controller('myctrl',function(){
       param="bye"
    })
    .directive('oldie', function() {
        return{
            restrict:"E",
            template: function(elem,attr) {
                 return "<div >Hello "+ attr.battr +" </div>"
            }
        }
    })
    .directive('adir', function() {
        return {
            restrict:"E",
            template: function(elem,attr){
                return "<oldie battr={{" + attr.aattr + "}}></oldie>"
            }
        }  
    });
```

What I need is to give the content of param to an attribute to be used in a directive.

I've done a jsfiddle to play:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eccit/9eg8ywbp/)

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few places wrong in your code.

1. You have used "ng-ctrl" instead of `ng-controller`. So, the controller is not effective at all.

   ```
    <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">
   ```
2. You haven't defined the $scope variable in the controller.

   ```
   .controller('myctrl',function($controller){
   ```
3. In your first directive, you don't have to use angular expressions `{{}}` when setting an attribute in the template. It can be a plain string.

   ```
   return "<oldie battr=" + attr.aattr + "></oldie>"
   ```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/9eg8ywbp/3/) is the fiddle.

Also an alternative to this approach is accessing the attributes through bindings in an isolated scope.

Please see the section Directive Definition Object on [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) article.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. As I've said it was a code simplification and errors you detected are just typing errors I've done on "simplification". I'm sorry. So really doesn't answer my problem (my fault, of course). On the other hand, your modifications and having a working code to emulate have aided me to find where was my problem. So thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Hi once u creating the template directive u need the scope to get the values so from the directive u have to specify the scope

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.message = "Product created!";
})

app.directive('adir', function() {
        return{
            restrict:"E",
            scope: {
            aattr: '@'
        },
      template: '<oldie  battr= {{aattr}} ></oldie>'

    }  
  })

  app.directive('oldie', function() {
    return{
            restrict:"E",
                scope: {
            battr: '@'
        },
      template: '<div class="alert">Hello  {{battr}}</div>'
    }
  })
```

HTML

```
 <adir aattr="{{message}}" >
   </adir>
```

for refrence
https://plnkr.co/edit/AjQnENCvPOU9xWzdylFL